# Multiple dates token for auto node title

Tags: 7, datetime, tokens

I am using this token to create node title [node:field-date-concert:custom:j-m-Y] and it works fine if there is one value for date in node.

Problem is that if there are 2 or more values i only get first one displayed but would like to get them all.
So instead of just showing 05-05-2016 as node title, i would like to have 05-05-2016, 15-06-2016, 28-07-2016.

Comment: You might be able to accomplish this with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), using a loop. Unfortunately, I don't have time to solve this one. Else, you could create a custom module and use hook_node_SOMETHING (perhaps: insert, update, or presave depending on when you want it to happen.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code snippet in your auto_nodetitle configuration.
Don't forget to select the option "Evaluate PHP in pattern.".
And replace the field_date_multiple with your own field's machine name.

Hope this helps!

```
<?php

$dates = array();
foreach($node->field_date_multiple[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $date){
  $dates[] = date('j-m-Y', strtotime($date['value']));
}
echo implode(', ', $dates);

?>
```